# Error while requesting a transaction with CXStartCallAction

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, callkit

I use CallKit, at runtime outgoing call I also call this function

```
private func startCall(handle: String, video: Bool = false, uuid: UUID) {
        let handle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
        let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: handle)
        startCallAction.isVideo = video

        let transaction = CXTransaction()
        transaction.addAction(startCallAction)

        requestTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func requestTransaction(_ transaction: CXTransaction, completion: ((_ error: Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        callController.request(transaction) { error in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Error requesting transaction", error.localizedDescription, transaction.actions)
            } else {
                debugPrint("Requested transaction successfully")
            }
            completion?(error)
        }
    }
```

But I get an error during the transaction request.

**Error requesting transaction" "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction error 2.)**

How can I fix it?

Update: When the device receives incoming calls, all transactions are executed without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my mistake, since I did not initialize `ProviderDelegate`, after initialization everything works as it should.

Comment: It happens to me as well, thanks for posting!